Постоянный редирект при парсинге страницы с определенным url
Делаю парсер страницы дром.ру со следующим url: https://kurgan.drom.ru/hyundai/sonata/generation5/?distance=500&maxprice=850000&transmission[]=-1&transmission[]=2&transmission[]=5&transmission[]=3&transmission[]=4&xv=2.2&ph=1&unsold=1
В ответе всегда получаю код перенаправления 301, либо исключение TooManyRedirects.
Но если из параметров убрать все transmission - все ок, ответ 200.
Также используя session.get_redirect_target(resp=response) и принтуя результат, ссылка определяется не полностью - до первых квадратных скобок (то есть синим подчеркнутым выделяется только часть ссылки).
Проблема в скобках или в чем-то другом? Как правильно в редиректами работать?
cookies = {формирование curlconverter-ом}
headers = {формирование curlconverter-ом}
s = requests.Session()
response = s.get(
        'https://kurgan.drom.ru/hyundai/sonata/generation5/?distance=500&maxprice=850000&transmission[]=-1&transmission[]=2&transmission[]=5&xv=2.2&ph=1&unsold=1',
        cookies=cookies,
        headers=headers,
        allow_redirects=False
    )
redirect_response = s.get_redirect_target(resp=response)
print(response)
print(redirect_response)


Замена скобок на %5B и %5D проблему не решает

Со ссылкой разобрался - в консоли так отображается, то есть ссылка целая, но редиректы так и мучают
